# Why do I get ORA-01438 error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, casting

I have an `EMPLOYEE` table with column(primary key) `EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6)`

And the following method to check whether an employee record exists in the table

```
public boolean exists(int employeeId) {

        Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        boolean exists = false;
        String stmt = "select EMPLOYEE_ID , FIRST_NAME , LAST_NAME , EMAIL , PHONE_NUMBER ,"
                + "HIRE_DATE , JOB_ID , SALARY , COMMISSION_PCT , MANAGER_ID , DEPARTMENT_ID "
                + " FROM EMPLOYEES where cast (EMPLOYEE_ID as Number(2)) = ?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(stmt);
            pstmt.setInt(1, employeeId);
            pstmt.execute(); //Returns true if the first object that the query returns is a ResultSet object
            exists = pstmt.getResultSet().next();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return exists;
    }
```

Now, in the `SQL` statement when I use `cast (EMPLOYEE_ID as Number(2)) = ?`  and call the `exists` method with input 2 `employeeOperations.exists(2);` I get the following error

`ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`

Why does this error occur, even when the size of the column is large enough?

It works well with input of 4 digits or more(maximum length of employee_id present in table is 4) i.e. `cast (EMPLOYEE_ID as Number(4)) = ?` works.

Comment: why are you casting to number(2)?  If employee_id can be up to 6, but why cast at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When casting from `NUMBER(6)` to `NUMBER(2)`, the records having `EMPLOYEE_ID` greater than 99 are causing the error (for example Oracle cannot put `100` in `\d{2}`).

Quick fix, use this request:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?
```

Comment: +1 one quick question can we have size of the column greater than the defined column size in the cast function? considering the above sample is it legal to write cast (EMPLOYEE_ID as Number(10)) ?